# Using memcache infront of a mongodb server

Tags: mongodb, memcached

I am trying to understand how mongo's internal cache works and if it does eliminate using memcache. Our database size is around 200G and index fits in the memory but after the index not much free memory left on the server.

One of my colleague says mongo's internal cache will be as fast as memcache so no need to introduce another level of complexity by using memcache.

The scenario in my head is when we read the data from db, it's saved in memcache and next time it's directly read from the cache instead of going back to db server. If the data is changed and needs to be saved/updated, it's done on both memcache server and database server.

I have been reading about this but couldn't convince myself yet. So I'd really appreciate if someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: It depends on your working set size, if that left over ram fits nicely for the working set then the extra layer could be unneeded complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is that a cache storage is different to a database. So MongoDB and SQL are different in purpose and usage when compared to Memcache.

Memcache is really good at lowering working set sizes for queries. For example: imagine a huge aggregated query with subselects and `CASE` statements and what not in SQL (think of the most complex query you can), doing this query in realtime all the time could cause the computer(s) to "thrash" (not to mention the problems client side).

However as everyone knows you need only summarise this query to another collection/table for it to be instantly faster. The real speed of memcache comes from the fact that it is a in memory key value store. This is where MongoDB could fail in speed because it is not memory stored, it is memory mapped but not stored.

MongoDB does no self caching, providing the query is "hot" and in LRU (this is where your working set comes in) you shouldn't notice much of a difference in response times. A good way to ensure a query is "hot" is to run it. Some people have a script of their biggest queries that they run to warm up the cache.

As I said memcache is a cache layer this is why:

> If the data is changed and needs to be saved/updated, it's done on both memcache server and database server.

Makes me die a little inside. Many do blur the line between the DB and the cache layer.